# Adding Open Graph support to Sitefinity version 8

Tags: facebook-opengraph, sitefinity

We are running our website through Sitefinity CMS version 8. While I'd like to get it upgraded to the latest and greatest that's out of my hands right now.

The problem we're having is that when our marketing team is trying to set up Hootsuite with new Twitter and Facebook posts that reference our blog on the Sitefinity site, the images do not embed themselves into the new posts. According to the [Sharing Debugger on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/), the problem is this:

> Warnings That Should Be Fixed
>
> Inferred Property
>
> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be  inferred from other tags.
>
> Missing Properties
>
> The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

I found the following link on the Sitefinity support site [that shows how to set up Open Graph in version 10.2](https://docs.sitefinity.com/open-graph-settings), but that's not what we have. I haven't been able to find anything in other versions of SiteFinity and the instructions given in the link don't apply to our version.

Has anyone else been able to set this up properly?  And if so... how'd you do it?

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the og meta tags explicitly from the view like this:

```
    var meta = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta();
    meta.Attributes.Add("property", "og:image");
    meta.Content = yourImage;

    // Get the current page handler in order to access the page header
    var pageHandler = this.ViewContext.HttpContext.Handler.GetPageHandler();
    pageHandler.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

I have done this on Detail Templates, using the dynamic module fields as content for the meta tags and it has worked for me.